# Do $|s(t)|$ and $|S(f)|$ uniquely determine $s(t)$?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

Consider a signal $s(t)$. My question is if you know $|s(t)|$ and $|\mathcal{FT}[s(t)](f)| = |S(f)|$ or equivalently $|s(t)|^2$ and $|S(f)|^2$ is it possible to determine $s(t)$? That is, is $s(t)$ uniquely determined by $|s(t)|$ and $|S(f)|$?

My strong feeling is that the answer is no but I can't come up with two signals $s_1(t) \neq s_2(t)$ which have the same magnitude and whose Fourier transforms have the same magnitude. Actually I can come up with trivial examples but that doesn't fully satisfy me. Let me share by work so far.

First of all, if we consider

$s_2(t) = s_1(t) e^{i\phi}$

Where $\phi$ is any real constant number then we clearly see that

\begin{align}
S_2(f) = S_1(f) e^{i\phi}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
|s_2(t)| &= |s_1(t)|\\
|S_2(f)| &= |S_1(f)|
\end{align}

So this example is a clear counterexample. However, this is just a trivial global phase that cannot be determined. That is, it is clear now that there is global phase multiplier that cannot be determined if only $|s(t)|$ and $|S(f)|$ are known. But, lets say that we either don't care about an overall phase factor or we happen to know that $s(0) = |s(0)|$ so that this global phase can be fixed.

Is it possible to come up with a non-trivial example of two functions which are a counterexample to what I am asking? I can phrase it this way.

If $|s_2(t)|= |s_1(t)|$ then

\begin{align}
s_2(t) = \Phi(t)s_1(t)
\end{align}

Where $|\Phi(t)|=1$ for all $t$. We then have that (by the convolution theorem)

\begin{align}
S_2(f) = S_1(f) \ast \Phi(f)
\end{align}

The question is is it possible for

\begin{align}
|S_2(f)| = |S_1(f)\ast\Phi(f)| = |S_1(f)|
\end{align}

If a non-trivial $\Phi(t)$ could be demonstrated then it would be clear that $|s(t)|$ and $|S(f)|$ do not uniquely determine $s(t)$ in any sense but I can't seem to come up with anything.

If I am wrong and it turns out that $|s(t)|$ and $|S(f)|$ do in fact uniquely determine $s(t)$ then could anyone provide a method to determine $s(t)$ (up to a missing overall phase) from $|s(t)|$ and $|S(f)|$?

Comment: This seems closely related to the concept of minimum phase. For a given |S(f)|, there's a process to calculate the corresponding minimum phase, which then gets you S(f) and hence S(t). See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7872/derive-minimum-phase-from-magnitude for example

Comment: Your notation is dreadful with $S(\cdot)$ meaning two _different_ functions depending on whether the $\cdot$ is replaced by $t$ or by $f$. How about _editing_ your question to make it more reasonable? -1 pending suitable editing.

Comment: I suggest replacing $S(f) = \mathcal{FT}\left [ S(t) \right ]$ with $X(\omega) = \mathcal{F}\left\lbrace x(t) \right\rbrace$ (because it's the most common notation, and $s$ is the Laplace frequency variable and thus confusing in this context).

Comment: I don't think you could do this in general -- in fact, if I were a bit better at minding my p's and q's I think I could disprove your hypothesis on the basis that any non-constant $\phi(t)$ is going to have a transform $\Phi(\omega)$ that, in general, would smear out a generic $X(\omega)$.  There may be more complicated instances of $x(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ that would work, but I think they'd have to be matched pairs.

Comment: I've changed $S(t)$ to $s(t)$ to avoid confusion with $\mathcal{FT}[s(t)](f) = S(f)$. It may not be the clearest notation in the world but it doesn't obscure the meaning of the question.

Comment: So how about fixing the _title_ of the question where the same confusing notation still reigns supreme?

Comment: @DilipSarwate it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment by Jazzmaniac, the proof below is flawed. The mistake I made was the assumption leading to Eq. $(3)$. Of course, $|S_1(f)|=|S_2(f)|$ implies that the two spectra are related by an all-pass transformation, but the phase of that all-pass can be dependent on the input signal, and hence need not be LTI.

One example of two signals satisfying $|s_1(t)|=|s_2(t)|$ and $|S_1(f)|=|S_2(f)|$ without satisfying $(1)$ is $s_1(t)=e^{j\phi(t)}$ and $s_2(t)=e^{-j\phi(-t)}$. Clearly, $|s_1(t)|=|s_2(t)|=1$. Since $s_2(t)=s_1^*(-t)$, the corresponding spectra satisfy $S_2(f)=S_1^*(f)$, and, consequently, $|S_1(f)|=|S_2(f)|$.

The dual case would be $S_1(f)=e^{j\Phi(f)}$ and $S_2(f)=S_1^*(-f)=e^{-j\Phi(-f)}$. The signals $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$ then satisfy $s_2(t)=s^*_1(t)$ and $|s_1(t)|=|s_2(t)|$.

The second example above requires the signals to be complex-valued (otherwise $s_1(t)=s_2(t)$ would hold). However, the first example also includes the real-valued case, i.e., a signal $s_1(t)$ that only attains two values: either $1$ or $-1$ (like a [telegraph process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegraph_process)). With $s_2(t)=s_1(-t)$ we guarantee $|s_1(t)|=|s_2(t)|$, and since $S_2(f)=S_1(-f)=S_1^*(f)$ we also have $|S_1(f)|=|S_2(f)|$.

---

**OLD answer:**

I think I can show that the trivial case

$$s_2(t)=e^{j\alpha}s_1(t),\qquad\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$

is the only case for which $|s_1(t)|=|s_2(t)|$ and $|S_1(f)|=|S_2(f)|$ holds.

From the requirement $|s_1(t)|=|s_2(t)|$ it follows that

$$s_2(t)=e^{j\phi(t)}s_1(t)\tag{2}$$

with a real-valued function $\phi(t)$. From the requirement $|S_1(f)|=|S_2(f)|$ it follows that $s_2(t)$ can be obtained from $s_1(t)$ by all-pass filtering:

$$s_2(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s_1(\tau)h_{AP}(t-\tau)d\tau\tag{3}$$

with $H_{AP}(f)=\mathcal{F}\{h_{AP}(t)\}$ satisfying $|H_{AP}(f)|=1$.

Since the multiplication in $(2)$ is memoryless, Equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ can only give the same result if $h_{AP}(t)=e^{j\alpha}\delta(t)$, i.e., for a trivial all-pass which just scales the input by a complex constant with magnitude equal to $1$. Consequently, the function $\phi(t)$ in $(2)$ must be constant (and equal to $\alpha$). This means that $(2)$ and $(3)$ are reduced to Eq. $(1)$.

Consequently, given $|s_1(t)|$ and $|S_1(f)|$, the signal $s_1(t)$ is determined up to a complex factor with magnitude $1$. I just do not know of any method to actually compute $s_1(t)$ from these two magnitude functions.

Comment: It looks like the Gerchberg-Saxton algorithm is a standard way to do the reconstruction: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerchberg–Saxton_algorithm or https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.4756.pdf#page17

Comment: @Jagerber48: Thanks for the link, never heard of that algorithm.

Comment: I don't think so: $\exp(i f(t))$ and $\exp(-i f(-t))$ for any real-valued $f$ are counter examples. Your assumption that the signals must be related by an LTI system is too restritive.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: Thanks, you're right. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a phase retrieval problem with additional knowledge. Finite support seems important. In 
[Enforcing uniqueness in one-dimensional phase retrieval by additional signal information in time domain](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.acha.2016.12.002), 2018, Applied and Computational Harmonic Analysis, the following statement is given (*section 3.2. The moduli of the entire signal*):

> Next, we will investigate the question whether every signal $x$ can be
>   uniquely recovered up to rotations if more then one modulus $|x[n]|$ or
>   even all moduli $(|x[n]|)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ are given. Phase
>   retrieval problems of this kind, where the complete modulus of the
>   signal is known, have been numerically studied in [References]. Based
>   on our findings in the last subsection, we immediately obtain the
>   following statement.
>
> Corollary 2. Almost every complex-valued signal $x$ with support $\{0,..., N−1\}$
>    can be uniquely recovered from $|\hat{x}|$ and
>   $(|x[n]|)^{N−1}_{n=0}$ up to rotations. Unfortunately, the additional
>   knowledge of more than one modulus of the signal in time domain does
>   not ensure uniqueness of the solution of the corresponding phase
>   retrieval problem in general, even if the complete modulus $|x|
> > :=(|x[n]|)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of the signal $x$ is given.

And then:

> Theorem 4. For every integer $N>3$, there exists a signal $x$ with
>   support $\{0,..., N−1\}$ such that $x $ cannot be uniquely recovered
>   from $|\hat{x}|$ and $|x|$ up to rotations.

More conditions and numerical algorithms are reviewed in the preprint [Fourier Phase Retrieval: Uniqueness and Algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09590), 2017 (Tamir Bendory, Robert Beinert, Yonina C. Eldar):  Gerchberg-Saxton, Griffin-Lim, etc.